# RSA or DSA: What's the definitive answer when generating SSH key pairs?

Tags: ssh, encryption, ssh-keygen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH keypair generation: RSA or DSA?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40071/ssh-keypair-generation-rsa-or-dsa)

Some say use RSA, some say use DSA, some say it doesn't matter.

Some say one is more secure than the other, some say the reverse.

Some say it's a patent issue.

- So, what's the real story here? Pros and cons, etc?
- In the end either will do, but for the fastidious security-minded person, which one is a better fit?
- Should one bother with mandating that the entire company use the same encryption?

### Update

Ah, turns out this is an exact dupe of [q40071](https://serverfault.com/questions/40071/ssh-keypair-generation-rsa-or-dsa), and the accepted answer there is ok.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, both are equally secure (read: both have no known weaknesses, which is really all you can say). So it does not matter which one you choose.

As far as I know, DSA was introduced because RSA was patented (at least in the USA), and a patent-free alternative was desired.

Answer (score 3):

I think that possibly the correctness of the implementation is equally important. If you've got a weak implementation of a strong algorithm then you've instantly weakened it

I would have thought that the defaults that are provided are sufficient for most cases. I can't imagine that the authors of any tools would provide default options that were inherently weak

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a difference in the key-size. This may be something to consider.

Comment: Well, you can always use -b to generate a key of different length.

Comment: Ah, DSA is fixed size

Comment: Yes it is. So, it is something to consider.